# Remote controller for python processes

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess, monitoring, supervisord

I have two `Twitter Streaming APIs` running on a machine, both of which are `python` processes and running on `supervisor`. I want to design a controller which can, **on command**, stop/start/restart the two processes.

One way is to have a web API exposed on that machine and hit that URL whenever a change of state is needed. It can use `subprocess` to restart Supervisord.

I was reading up [Pyro](https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro/1-intro.html) and it seemed to be a solution which would take away the need for the API system in the above step.

Anything I'm  missing or any other solution which is an upgrade on these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that supervisor can do that for you, check this out

http://supervisord.org/api.html

Supervisor include an xml rpc to control the processes under it, you just need to configure it. Take a look at the documentation and on this guide

http://devo.ps/blog/using-supervisord-for-your-deploy-pipelines/

He configure the rpc interface there

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, I would expose a REST api using CherryPy running as a daemon.
It's simpler and the only thing you need to control it is a request. You can add parameters and later maker richer with some other request if you want. Also, you can use it in Windows as a windows service.
https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.6/refman/process/plugins/daemonizer.html

Answer (score 0):

Cluster management tools are a perfect match for a use case like that. The benefit you get is that the solution would even work when you have more than one machines. 
Check ansible supervisor plugin for example: 
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/supervisorctl_module.html

You would only have to invoke a command from a remote machine running ansible and since it is agentless it will take care of the rest. See below a playbook I wrote for something similar:

```
    ---
    - hosts: webservers
      user: admin
      sudo: yes
      sudo_user: root
      vars:
        node_env: "{{ DEPLOY_ENV|default(staging) }}"
      vars_files:
        - ../vars/secret
        - ../vars/main.yml
        - ../defaults/main.yml

      tasks:

      # Manage Supervisor web tasks - restart them in a specific order
      - name: Restart Data API supervisor Job
        supervisorctl: name="web:data_api" state=restarted
      - name: Restart Data API-2 supervisor Job
        supervisorctl: name="web:data_api2" state=restarted

      handlers:
       - name: test all
         shell: source /etc/profile.d/go-api.sh && source /etc/profile.d/go-path.sh && source /etc/profile.d/go-bin.sh && cd /opt/go/src/github.com/pgaref/data_api && go test . ./... executable=/bin/bash
         shell: source /etc/profile.d/go-api.sh && source /etc/profile.d/go-path.sh && source /etc/profile.d/go-bin.sh && cd /opt/go/src/github.com/pgaref/data_api2 && go test . ./... executable=/bin/bash
```